# Oracle, NULL but not NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, null, oracle-sqldeveloper, isnull

If I run this query on my oracle database:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, 
       DATA_DEFAULT, 
       DATA_TYPE
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' 
   AND DATA_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL;
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
STOICHIOMETRY   NULL    NUMBER
```

My Question is WHY? I've asked for not NULL.

If I run:

```
describe MY_TABLE
```

I get:

```
Name          Null     Type         
------------- -------- ------------ 
TID           NOT NULL NUMBER(9)    
COMPONENT_ID  NOT NULL NUMBER(9)    
RELATIONSHIP  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
STOICHIOMETRY          NUMBER(3)    
TARGCOMP_ID   NOT NULL NUMBER(9)    
HOMOLOGUE     NOT NULL NUMBER(1)
```

Comment: Do you have the definition of 'MY_TABLE'?

Comment: @Taemyr - yes, the question is updated now.

Comment: @alfasin - that's very sweet.

Comment: @mnowotka I checked both with `is not null` and `is null` just to make sure. I don't think it has anything to do with the table structure but honestly I have no idea...

Comment: @alfasin - what I would like to know in this question is all (even most strange) cases when such a thing could happen. My DBA says it may be bacause: 'I think either because of the order I did things (ie I set the default after I populated with some null values - I don't think it automatically applies the default retrospectively), OR I used a query to explicitly set the value to null (in this case the default doesn't apply).'

Comment: Both explanations sounds weird, I think it's time to call the heavy cannon: @JustinCave - can you help ?

Comment: You probably set NULL as your default value for a column. Only in this situation `DATA_DEFAULT` column would literally contain `null` value.

Comment: Yes, but I want to filter this out from my results...
That's why I have this NOT NULL part. What should I put instead?

Comment: Use `DATA_DEFAULT<>'NULL'`

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to check if a column is nullable or the default value of a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think NULL is your default value?  For example I have a table and I've altered the default value to NULL:

```
ALTER TABLE UNIQUEVALTEST MODIFY ZIP DEFAULT NULL;
```

Now when I select:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_DEFAULT
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'UNIQUEVALTEST'
AND data_default IS NOT NULL;
```

I get:

```
ZIP NULL
```

Edit: To explain better, if the field was (null), then there is no default value.  But the default value is now set to NULL, so any new data inserted would automatically be NULL unless specified otherwise.  I don't know if that changes the functionality at all (having no default value, or having the default value set to NULL), but I would think it would operate the same.

Answer (score 2):

The nullability of a column is stored in `NULLABLE`, not in `DATA_DEFAULT`. The `DATA_DEFAULT` stores the default value for a column (and if you haven't provided a default value in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, all columns get `DEFAULT NULL` (even non-nullable ones!)

Try:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, 
       DATA_DEFAULT, 
       DATA_TYPE,
       NULLABLE
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' 
   AND NULLABLE = 'N';              -- 'N' means No, not nullable
                                    -- 'Y' means Yes, nullable
```

Comment: The situation is a bit different here. When you assign `NULL` as a default value for a column upon table creation, the `DATA_DEFAULT`(which of long datatype) will literally contain `null` - string literal. I think that the OP's problem.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov It's not clear if the OP wants to test agaisnt the nullability or the default value of the columns. I assumed the first because he added the Describe but I could be wrong. You are right about the string `'NULL'` stored in `DATA_DEFAULT`. The query would be `AND DATA_DEFAULT <> 'NULL'` in this case (if only that was allowed for LONGs !)

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that you, as @Rob [correctly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875250/997660), assigned `NULL` as a default value for a column. 
Unfortunately, [you cannot remove](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#sthref3374) once assigned default value for a column - the `data_default` column of `user_tab_columns` data dictionary view will always contain data.

> Note: If a column has a default value, then you can use the DEFAULT
>   clause to change the default to NULL, but you cannot remove the
>   default value completely. If a column has ever had a default value
>   assigned to it, then the DATA_DEFAULT column of the USER_TAB_COLUMNS
>   data dictionary view will always display either a default value or
>   NULL.

If you want this condition `DATA_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL` to succeed, the only option is to recreate the column without `default` clause.

1. create a new column
2. Copy data from the *damaged* one
3. Drop the column, which has been created with `default` clause
4. Rename the newly created column.

Example:

```
create table TB_Test(
  col number default null
);

insert into tb_test(col)
  select level
   from dual
   connect by level <= 11;


select column_name,
       data_default,
       data_type
  from user_tab_columns
  where table_name = upper('tb_test')
    and data_default is not null

Column_Name Data_Default Data_Type 
--------------------------------------
COL         null         NUMBER 
             ^
             |
        string literal

SQL> alter table tb_test add col2 number;
Table altered

update tb_test
   set col2 = col

SQL> alter table tb_test drop column col;
Table altered

SQL> alter table tb_test rename column col2 to col;
Table altered

select column_name,
       data_default,
       data_type
  from user_tab_columns
  where table_name = upper('tb_test')
    and data_default is not null

no rows selected
```